# Function is only called once in page navigation

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I am trying to program a page that downloads images from a firebase storage folder and displays them in a grid. I have no problem with this when I first navigate to this page. But once I navigate to another page and then back to this page, the images don't load anymore. The function `getImage()` is what loads the images. And it's called in `initState()`. Is it because it's only called once when the page first opens?

Here's the code snippet of the page navigation:

```
class RouteGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    // Getting arguments passed in while calling Navigator.pushNamed
    final args = settings.arguments;

    switch (settings.name) {
...
 case '/stichpage':
        // Validation of correct data type
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => ImagesScreen(),
        );
...  
}
```

And this is the actual code for the page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dataholder.dart';

class ImagesScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget makeImagesGrid() {
    return GridView.builder(
        itemCount: "objectname".length,
        gridDelegate:
            SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ImageGridItem(index);
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
        elevation: 5,
        title: Text('Image Stitching'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: makeImagesGrid(),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        color: Colors.grey[200],
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Spacer(),
            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.save), onPressed: () {}),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        onPressed: () {},
        icon: Icon(Icons.burst_mode),
        label: Text('Stitch'),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    );
  }
}

class ImageGridItem extends StatefulWidget {
  int _index;

  ImageGridItem(int index) {
    this._index = index;
  }

  @override
  _ImageGridItemState createState() => _ImageGridItemState();
}

class _ImageGridItemState extends State<ImageGridItem> {
  Uint8List imageFile;
  StorageReference photosReference =
      FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("images");

  getImage() {
    if (!requestedIndexes.contains(widget._index)) {
      int maxSize = 7 * 1024 * 1024;
      photosReference
          .child("cell${widget._index}.png")
          .getData(maxSize)
          .then((data) {
        this.setState(() {
          imageFile = data;
        });
        imageData.putIfAbsent(widget._index, () {
          return data;
        });
      }).catchError((error) {
        debugPrint(error.toString());
      });
      requestedIndexes.add(widget._index);
    }
  }

  Widget decideGridTileWidget() {
    if (imageFile == null) {
      return Center(child: Text(""));
    } else {
      return Image.memory(
        imageFile,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      );
    }
  }

   @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (!imageData.containsKey(widget._index)) {
      getImage();
    } else {
      this.setState(() {
        imageFile = imageData[widget._index];
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridTile(child: decideGridTileWidget());
  }
}
```

And the code that holds the image data:

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

Map<int, Uint8List> imageData = {};

List<int> requestedIndexes = [];
```

Comment: When you say "navigate out" you mean push another view? or pop to a previous view?

Comment: Push to another view. Basically the page navigation code snippet but instead of `'/stichpage'` it's `'/dashboard'`

Answer (score 1):

When you push to another view the previous view is kept in the `Navigator`, so when you pop back to it, it does rebuild but it wont call the `initState` again.

If you want to actually do something when your screen comes back to be primary after a pop you need to implement a `RouteObserver` e.g.

```
final RouteObserver<PageRoute> routeObserver = RouteObserver<PageRoute>();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            theme: ThemeData(),
            navigatorObservers: [routeObserver],
            home: Screen1(),
            routes: {
                'screen2': (context) => Screen2(),
                'screen3': (context) => Screen3(),
            },
        );
     }
}
```

Once you have that in your main, you need your screen to be `RouteAware`

```
class Screen3 extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _Screen3State createState() => _Screen3State(); 
}

class _Screen3State extends State<Screen3> with RouteAware {
    @override
    void didChangeDependencies() {
        super.didChangeDependencies();
        RouteObserverProvider.of(context).subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context));
     }

     @override
     void dispose() {
         RouteObserverProvider.of(context).unsubscribe(this);
         super.dispose();
     }

     @override
     void didPush() {
         print('didPush Screen3');
     }

     @override
     void didPopNext() {
         print('didPopNext Screen3');
     }
}
```

The one you actually need is `didPopNext`.

There is a nice post in Medium by David Anaya that you can look for [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-track-screen-transitions-in-flutter-with-routeobserver-733984a90dea)

Comment: This partially works. The images are still there, but they don't load up. So if I were to delete a photo from the firebase folder, go to the dashboard and come back, the number of images on the page don't change, even though there should be one fewer.

Comment: hm.. not sure how are you calculating the amount of images because this is wrong ```itemCount: "objectname".length,``` though it was dummy code (since you are using a fixed string length) but if you are actually using that, there is your issue.

Comment: I don't think the `itemCount` is that relevant. Sure I can change it to a number like 10, but I am only showing the images with the name cell0.png, cell1.png, cell2.png, cell3.png, etc. In my folder, I have those four photos, and that's what it's displaying. But if I deleted cell3.png, go to dashboard and back, cell3.png is still there, even though it should not. This is the issue.